# Ruby - Using class_eval to define methods

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-eval

I'm doing the SaaS Stanford class, trying to do Part 5 of [this assignment](http://spark-university.s3.amazonaws.com/berkeley-saas/homework/hw1.pdf)

I'm having a really hard time grasping this concept, this is what I've attempted to do:

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name
    attr_reader attr_name + '_history'
    class_eval %Q'{def #{attr_name}(a);#{attr_name}_history.push(a) ; end;}'
  end
end
```

I'm probably doing all sorts of things wrong, read The Book Of Ruby chapter on metaprogramming and I still don't get it, can someone help me comprehend this?

Comment: Does this actually work?  If not, what's the problem?  Not really sure what the question is asking for here!

Comment: have a look  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658724/ruby-metaprogramming-class-eval/9658775#9658775   it is the same homework question

Comment: Yeah, and by the date I asked it first :P

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This was fun!!!

```
class Class
    def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
        attr_name = attr_name.to_s # make sure it's a string
        attr_reader attr_name
        attr_reader attr_name+"_history"
        class_eval %Q"
            def #{attr_name}=(value)
                if !defined? @#{attr_name}_history
                    @#{attr_name}_history = [@#{attr_name}]
                end
                @#{attr_name} = value
                @#{attr_name}_history << value
            end
        "
    end
end

class Foo
    attr_accessor_with_history :bar
end

class Foo2
    attr_accessor_with_history :bar
    def initialize()
        @bar = 'init'
    end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 1
f.bar = nil
f.bar = '2'
f.bar = [1,nil,'2',:three]
f.bar = :three
puts "First bar:", f.bar.inspect, f.bar_history.inspect
puts "Correct?", f.bar_history == [f.class.new.bar, 1, nil, '2', [1,nil,'2',:three], :three] ? "yes" : "no"
old_bar_history = f.bar_history.inspect

f2 = Foo2.new
f2.bar = 'baz'
f2.bar = f2
puts "\nSecond bar:", f2.bar.inspect, f2.bar_history.inspect
puts "Correct?", f2.bar_history == [f2.class.new.bar, 'baz', f2] ? "yes" : "no"

puts "\nIs the old f.bar intact?", f.bar_history.inspect == old_bar_history ? "yes" : "no"
```

Note that the only reason you need to use strings with class_eval is so that you can refer to the *value* of `attr_name` when defining the custom setter. Otherwise one would normally pass a block to `class_eval`.

Comment: Explain the concepts! Don't just give the answer! You are really hurting more people than helping.

Comment: What does this section do? def #{attr_name}=(value). I mean what are we actually defining here?

Comment: Please don't revive year-old questions unless you have something important to contribute, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

With regard to what you've done you're actually on the cusp of the solution. It's just that  `#{attr_name}_history` doesn't exist in your code. You will need to create an instance variable and set it to nil if it doesn't exist. What you have already should handle pushing into the array if it does exist.

There are several ways to do that. One way is  `if defined? @#{attr_name}_history DoStuffHere`

Answer (score 0):

You must notice that `#{attr_name}_history` is a instance variable, so use @ before, like @foo in the class below

`def #{attr_name}=value`, `#{attr_name}=` is the method name, `value` is parameter, same as `def func parameter`

```
def #{attr_name}=value
  (!defined? @#{attr_name}_history) ? @#{attr_name}_history = [nil, value] : @#{attr_name}_history << value
end
```