# Ruby issue with class_eval

Tags: ruby, setter, class-eval

I'm trying to run the following but i keep getting a

> "NoMethodError: undefined method `bar=' for #/Foo:0x86f69ba/"

```
    class Class
    def my_attr_accessor(name)

    attr_name = name.to_s  
    attr_reader name       
    attr_reader "my_"+name 
    class_eval %Q"def #{name}=(val)
                 @#{name}=val
                 end"
      end

    end
```

I'm actually using something similar to this post: [Ruby - Using class_eval to define methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561072/ruby-using-class-eval-to-define-methods)

EDITED: you're quite right I made the change to reflect this.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`class_eval` is a method, but you are assigning a variable here (`class_eval =`)

Comment: you should also use `define_method` instead of a `class_eval`

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why? I'd be interested to know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @user1994202 evaluating strings instead of blocks is 1) computationally expensive, 2) chronically unsafe -- it's too easy to end up interpolating untrusted data into the string eval allowing external attackers the ability to execute arbitrary code in your process.